# set up custom port for default ssh connection in tramp

Tags: tramp, ssh

I am wondering what is the best way to set up a default port that is not the standard 22 port. I regularly log in with tramp to remote systems and would like to avoid having to put in #1234 every time I connect.

My tramp config (org-mode) looks as follows

```
* Tramp
For TRAMP to work with ssh-key, install the programm ssh-askpass
 (https://github.com/markcarver/mac-ssh-askpass)
 C-x C-f /ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:remotehost:/path/to/file

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun url-clear-cookies ()
  "Clear all cookies."
  (interactive)
  (setq url-cookie-storage nil)
  (setq url-cookie-secure-storage nil))

(use-package password-cache
  :ensure nil
  :custom
  ;; Never expire passwords
  (password-cache-expiry nil))

(use-package tramp
  :ensure nil
  :custom
  (tramp-default-method "ssh"))

(defun add-ssh-agent-to-tramp ()
  (cl-pushnew '("-A")
              (cadr (assoc 'tramp-login-args
                           (assoc "ssh" tramp-methods)))
              :test #'equal))

(use-package tramp-sh
  :ensure nil
  :custom
  ;; Use out-of-band method for big files
  (tramp-copy-size-limit (* 0.5 1024 1024))
  :config
  ;; Use the PATH from the remote
  (add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path))

(use-package tramp-gvfs
  :ensure nil
  :after tramp-ftp
  :config
  ;; Prefer gvfs for FTP
  (add-to-list 'tramp-gvfs-methods "ftp"))

(defun local-file-name-as-sudo (file-name)
  "Transforms /foo/bar.ext into /sudo::/foo/bar.ext"
  (concat "/sudo::" file-name))

(defun tramp-file-name-as-sudo (file-name)
  "Transforms /scp:user@host:/foo/bar.ext into /ssh:user@host|sudo:host:/foo/bar.ext"
  (let* ((parts (tramp-dissect-file-name file-name))
         (host (tramp-file-name-host parts)))

    ;; replace "host:" by "host|sudo:host:"
    (setq file-name (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote (concat host ":"))
                                              (concat host "|sudo:" host ":")
                                              file-name t t))

    ;; replace scp by ssh otherwise sudo doens't work
    (setq file-name (replace-regexp-in-string "^/scp" "/ssh" file-name))))

(defun buffer-file-name-as-sudo (&optional buffer)
  "Return BUFFER filename as sudo"
  (require 'tramp)
  (let* ((buffer (or buffer (current-buffer)))
         (file-name (expand-file-name (or (buffer-file-name buffer) dired-directory))))
    (if (tramp-tramp-file-p file-name)
        (tramp-file-name-as-sudo file-name)
      (local-file-name-as-sudo file-name))))

(defun find-alternative-file-with-sudo ()
  (interactive)
  (find-alternate-file (buffer-file-name-as-sudo)))
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Don’t try this in tramp. Use your `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: thanks, and I thought that the above causes tramp to use SSH by default. But still I have to put in ssh every time. How can I change that?

Comment: Set `tramp-default-method` to set tramp’s default method ;)

Comment: I did that, ah shown above, still it does not work and only shows "file not found, if I leave out the SSH. If I put it, it works though

Comment: Try `(setq tramp-default-method “ssh”)` outside of your `use-package` statement.

Comment: Note that in recent tramp versions you *must* include a tramp method -- but you can specify it as `-` to use the configured default method.

Answer (score 2):

In your `init.el` you have

```lisp
(use-package tramp
  :ensure nil
  :custom
  (tramp-default-method "ssh"))
```

This should cause an error `Error (use-package): tramp/:config: Symbol’s function definition is void: tramp-default-method`. Doing:

```lisp
(use-package tramp
  :ensure nil
  :custom
  (setq tramp-default-method "ssh"))
```

works as expected. After startup, doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> `tramp-default-method`, gets you:

```lisp
tramp-default-method is a variable defined in ‘tramp.el’.
Its value is "ssh"
Original value was "scp"

Documentation:
Default method to use for transferring files.
See ‘tramp-methods’ for possibilities.
Also see ‘tramp-default-method-alist’.

You can customize this variable.
```

Now, in your `~/.ssh/config` you can do something like this to multi-hop to your work dekstop:

```lisp
Host work-desktop
ControlMaster yes
ProxyCommand ssh -q bastion.yoyody.ne:2222 -W work-desktop.internal:22
```

Tramp will now "do the right thing".

```lisp
M-x find-file /work-desktop:my_project.txt
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) I will try this. I didn't get an error though with my version

Comment: so I checked, and putting setq in front as you advised causes an error. In contrast omitting this, like I did from the start, works and I get the desired output if tested how the variable is set. However, if I want to connect to a remote server, I still have to put ssh, otherwise emacs hangs whilte trying to establlish the connection oO

Comment: Curious. Try moving your init file aside, and creating a minimal (non-org-mode) replacement that initializes packages and `use-package`'s tramp. You can try [my minimal version](http://codepad.org/V4uFk8ZL)

Comment: https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#customizing-variables